# Swift - CollectionView Inside View Controller - Data Exchange between them

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, collectionview, reloaddata

I am new to Swift programming, been using it for about 3 months now and this is my first attempt in iOS app development.
I am trying to create a calendar based appointment booking app.

All the features i am now explaining has been created programatically, no use of storyboard whatsoever.

**App Features:**
The App has a main viewcontroller with following subviews...

1. Top Subview - Month name (*along with an of image to give aesthetic appeal for app*)
2. Middle subview containing collectionview for calendar.
3. Third, last subview - to show up appointment slots available for day selected, open for booking

Main fearture in calendar is that range of dates (cells) are enabled or disabled. Indicating dates are open or not for appointment booking.
These range of dates will span across a week or few days. For example, dates 1 to 5 available for booking, again, 7 to 14, another set of dates may be 25th to 30th.
These sets of date cells are enabled and rest are disabled.

**Working correctly**
Selected cell (date) from CollectionView to send cell value to main View controller
I use delegate protocol. Selected date value is sent back successfully back to main view

**NOT WORKING & My Problem**
While I am able to pass the set of dates to calendar class, **the reload() is not working** to refresh calendar when months changed.
I want the range of dates passed to collectionview to be programatically enabled or disabled when calendar cells are reloaded.
I have swipe gesture enabled to swipe left and right to browse between months.

When I swipe right or left, I expect the new month to be loaded with new set of dates available for booking. While swipe seem to work, the new month is not reloaded, meaning, the collectionview reload is not working.

ViewController and another UIView class containing CollectionView are 2 classes I am using.

Can I get some help on this reloadData please?

Reverse way to pass data is totally now working, i.e., use delegate protocol to pass series of dates and use referencing class to pass selected date. Totally not working.
I have decided to continue to use delegate to pass selected date and class reference to pass date range.

**Code Image added showing attempt to refresh collectionview**[Code Image Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXuaW.png)

**Update - Code added in CollectionView Class**

```
func RegisterCalendar() {
    
    myCollectionView.dataSource = self
    myCollectionView.delegate = self
    myCollectionView.register(dateCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

func ProcessMonthDates(NewMonthStartDate: Date, NewMonthEndDate: Date) {
    HMonthSDate = NewMonthStartDate
    HMonthEDate = NewMonthEndDate
    myCollectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 35
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! dateCVCell
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
```

In main ViewController class:

```
@objc func swipeMade (_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
       if sender.direction == .left {
          NewMonthIndex = HMonthIndex - 1
       }
       if sender.direction == .right {
          NewMonthIndex = HMonthIndex + 1
       }
    let ReturnedValues = BuildNewMonths.GetNewHMonth(for: NewMonthIndex)
    ToSendNewMonthDates.ProcessMonthDates(NewMonthStartDate: ReturnedValues.0, NewMonthEndDate: ReturnedValues.1 )
```

**Update #2**
Reload now working, when I use it in mail view controller in swipeGesture routine, but the new set of date range is not passed into collectionview.

```
@objc func swipeMade (_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
       if sender.direction == .left {
          NewMonthIndex = HMonthIndex - 1
       }
       if sender.direction == .right {
          NewMonthIndex = HMonthIndex + 1
       }
    let ReturnedValues = BuildNewMonths.GetNewHMonth(for: NewMonthIndex)
    ToSendNewMonthDates.ProcessMonthDates(NewMonthStartDate: ReturnedValues.0, NewMonthEndDate: ReturnedValues.1)
    calenderView.myCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: i have added my code image

Comment: instead of image ... please post code in question

Comment: any other way I can implement a 2 way data exchange between viewcontroller and collectionview ???

Comment: @hbm You can exchange data via delegates.

Comment: can a single delegate send and receive data ? Can I get some example, especially one using collectionview will be helpful.